# In Ubuntu 18.04 after installing clamav, clamscan not working. After googling I did freshclam, that's failing download

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, clamav

I have installed clamav in Ubuntu 18.04 using

'''**sudo apt-get install clamav**'''

and tried clamscan but showing the error as follows:

---

```
LibClamAV Error: cli_loaddbdir(): No supported database files found in /var/lib/clamav
ERROR: Can't open file or directory

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 0
Engine version: 0.102.1
Scanned directories: 0
Scanned files: 0
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 0.00 MB
Data read: 0.00 MB (ratio 0.00:1)
Time: 0.004 sec (0 m 0 s)
***
```

After googling I removed entire clamav, installed again and tried sudo freshclam command, but showing the following error all times when clamav is updating:

---

```
Mon Jan 27 21:51:53 2020 -> ^Download failed (28) Mon Jan 27 21:51:53 2020 -> ^ Message: Timeout was reached
Mon Jan 27 21:51:53 2020 -> ^getcvd: Can't download daily.cvd from https://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd
Mon Jan 27 21:51:53 2020 -> Trying again in 5 secs...
^CMon Jan 27 21:51:57 2020 -> Update process terminated
```

---

It consumed my entire data and at final I terminated the process. I tried it more that 5 times, same result persist. Anybody please help me to figure out this issue.

Also I need to know which AV is better for Ubuntu Clamav or Comodo?

Thanks

Comment: Now after restarting, I am facing another issue for freshclam: 'ERROR: /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log is locked by another process
ERROR: Problem with internal logger (UpdateLogFile = /var/log/clamav/freshclam.log).
ERROR: initialize: libfreshclam init failed.
'

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be timing out getting the virus definition database. Are you able to connect directly to https://database.clamav.net/daily.cvd

It's a fairly large file (~58 MB) so it might not work if you're on a limited connection.

Comment: I have downloaded that file. So what will be next I have to do for getting clamav updated? Please help me.